# 'Failed to seal apk' after during the 'Project run' in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

After I've updated the Android Plugin for Gradle to the `2.0.0-alpha5` I'm constantly getting `Failed to seal APK` error while trying to run the project on my device. How I can solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be called by the `Instant run` feature of Android Studio. To make the error disappear, go to `Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run` and uncheck `Enable Instant Run to hot swap code/resource changes on deploy (default enabled)`.